# How to update kotlin data class with properties of a different data class

Tags: kotlin, data-class

If I have for example an entity:

```
   data class SampleEntity(
            val a: Int,
            val b: Int,
            val c: Int,
            val d: Int){
     fun update(form: SampleEntityUpdateForm): SampleEntity{
       ... 
       return this SampleEntity updated with form
     } 
}
```

and a form to update this entity:

```
data class SampleEntityUpdateForm(
        val a: Int?,
        val b: Int?,
        val c: Int?,
        val d: Int?
)
```

What is the best way to update the entity with this form (i.e. implementing SampleEntity.update(...)), leaving the properties that are null in SampleEntityUpdateForm as they were in the original entity, with minimum boiler plate.

So for example:

```
val sampleEntityInst = SampleEntity(1,2,3,4)

val sampleEntityUpdateForm(b = 20, d = 40)

val updatedSampleEntityInst = sampleEntityInst.update(sampleEntityUpdateForm)
```

where updatedSampleEntityInst will equal SampleEntity(1,20,3,40).

obviosly I could implement SampleEntity.update as:

```
fun update(form: SampleEntityUpdateForm) = SampleEntity(
        a = form.a ?: this.a,
        b = form.b ?: this.b,
        c = form.c ?: this.c,
        d = form.d ?: this.d,
)
```

But this has quite a bit of boiler plate/repetition. Is there something already made to allow doing this with less boiler plate/repetition?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without enumerating all props and without reflection. You should also consider what to do with props that are nullable in `SampleEntity`.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [copy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) method available on all data classes, e.g:

```kotlin
data class SampleEntity(
    val a: Int,
    val b: Int,
    val c: Int,
    val d: Int){
    fun update(form: SampleEntityUpdateForm): SampleEntity{

        return  this.copy(a = form.a, b = form.b, ...)
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I did miss the nullability twist. Using the `magic` function below the following works but it in my opinion the straightforward approach has better ergonomics.

There may be use cases where reflection is OK: a high number of properties, a tricky transformation of the incoming parameters, etc...

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val sampleEntityForm = SampleEntityUpdateForm(a = null, b = 20, c = null, d = 40)
    val sampleEntityInst = SampleEntity(1, 2, 3, 4)

    magic(sampleEntityForm, sampleEntityInst).also { 
        println(it) 
    } // prints: SampleEntity(a=1, b=20, c=3, d=40)
}


fun magic(from: SampleEntityUpdateForm, using: SampleEntity): SampleEntity {
    val fromValues = from::class.members.filterIsInstance<KProperty1<SampleEntityUpdateForm, Int?>>().map { it.get(from) }
    val usingValues = using::class.members.filterIsInstance<KProperty1<SampleEntity, Int>>().map { it.get(using) }

    val nullsEliminated = usingValues.mapIndexed { i, value -> fromValues[i] ?: value }.toTypedArray()

    return SampleEntity::class.primaryConstructor!!.call(*nullsEliminated)
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile this? It won't because `copy` accepts not-nullable values.

Comment: yeah I agree, this does not comply to specification of desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with static typing. Boilerplate and repetitiveness come built-in. I think your example with `a = form.a ?: this.a` is a good solution. Using a statically typed language like Kotlin, it's better to accept the boilerplate and move on.

If you want to be more fancy, you have to use something more dynamic. For example, you can go via JSON, which is more flexible. This solution uses [JSON-P](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jsonp/)'s [`JsonMergePatch`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jsonp/docs/impl/jakarta.json/jakarta/json/JsonMergePatch.html) to create a patch and apply it to your object. I'm using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to convert between POJOs and JSON objects via reflection.

This method has the benefit of being able to set values to `null` via the patch too. If the value in the patch is `null`, it sets the target value to `null`. If the value is not in the patch, the existing value is preserved. This is something you can't do nicely natively; you have to start going crazy with things like nullable `Optional`s.

```
fun main() {
    val original = SampleEntity(a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0)
    val patch = Json.createObjectBuilder()
        .add("b", 2)
        .add("d", 4)
        .build().let { Json.createMergePatch(it) }
    val patched: SampleEntity = original.update(patch)
    println(patched)
}

data class SampleEntity(
    val a: Int,
    val b: Int,
    val c: Int,
    val d: Int
) {
    fun update(patch: JsonMergePatch): SampleEntity {
        val jsonValue = objectMapper.convertValue<JsonValue>(this)
        val patched = patch.apply(jsonValue)
        return objectMapper.convertValue(patched)
    }

    companion object {
        private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()
            .registerKotlinModule()
            .registerModule(JSONPModule())
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SampleEntity(a=0, b=2, c=0, d=4)
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("jakarta.json", "jakarta.json-api", "2.0.1")
    implementation("org.glassfish", "jakarta.json", "2.0.1")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-core", "2.13.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype", "jackson-datatype-jakarta-jsonp", "2.12.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module", "jackson-module-kotlin", "2.13.0")
}
```